# Process video with frame averaging to produce long exposure final frame

Tags: ffmpeg, exposure-time

I'm looking for a FFMPEG script able to process a video file, create frame averaging and save latest long exposed frame.
My goal is to process the video enhancing the trasparent TV logo on the screen:
[image]

Is this viable via FFMPEG? thx